# PHP OOP Session Object - Won't Persist Without Serialize Un-Serialize

Tags: php

I'm trying to figure out why the code below won't persist my $_SESSION['objSession'] object across pages unless i keep the serialize/unserialize in place below.  I get tired of manually serializing/unserializing to make object changes in the session and people keep saying i shouldn't have to do it but i do see other complaints about session objects not persisting without it on the web including here on stack... PHP 5.3 Apache 2.2 Windows 2008.

```
<?php require_once("/php/php_clsSession.php");?>
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php
    // Session Object Create/Log
    $objSession = new clsSession;
    if ( !(isset($_SESSION['objSession']) )) {
        // This line will populate some properties in the obj
        // like Session_ID and Create_dt
        $objSession->CreateSession(session_id(),$_SERVER);
    }
    else {
        // this code will only run if the session is already 
        // set
        $objSession = unserialize($_SESSION['objSession']);
        $objSession->UpdateSession(session_id(),$_SERVER);
    }
    // Update Session Object
    $_SESSION['objSession'] = serialize($objSession);
    unset($objSession);
?>
```

---- clsSession Below this line... you can ignore the db include as the code has the same problem without using the db functionality and i have the db function temporarily commented anyhow....

```
<?php
   // -----------------------------------------------------------------
   // Program Type: Class
   // Program Name: clsSession
   // Program Date: 01/08/2012 Programmer: Tim Wiley
   // Description:  Standard class for session creation/update
   // -----------------------------------------------------------------
  class clsSession {

       // Properties
       public $Session_Id = null;
       public $Creation_Dt = null;
       public $Action_Dt = null;
       public $Session_IP_Address = null;
       public $Browser_Type = null;
       public $Display_Resolution = null;
       public $Is_Https_Ind = null;
       public $Is_Logged_In_Ind = 0;
       public $User_Key = null;
       public $User_Id = null;
       public $Email_Address = null;
       public $Request_Method = null;
       public $Page_Requested = null;
       public $Page_Request_Params = null;
       public $Page_Action = null;
       public $Login_Attempts = 0;
       public $Max_Login_Attempts = 3;

     private function UpdateSessionClassData (&$xSessionId = null, &$xSessionObj = null, &$xPageAction = "N/A" ) {
        $this->Session_Id = &$xSessionId;
        $this->Action_Dt = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time( ));
        $this->Session_IP_Address = substr(trim(&$xSessionObj['REMOTE_ADDR']),0,24);
        $this->Browser_Type = substr(trim(&$xSessionObj['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),0,140);
        $this->Request_Method = substr(trim(&$xSessionObj['REQUEST_METHOD']),0,24);
        $this->Page_Requested = substr(trim(&$xSessionObj['SCRIPT_NAME']),0,140);
        $this->Page_Request_Params = substr(trim(&$xSessionObj['QUERY_STRING']),0,140);
        $this->Is_Https_Ind = &$xSessionObj['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? 1 : 0;
        if (is_null($this->Display_Resolution)) {
            require_once('/javascript/js_SaveScreenResolutionInCookie.js');
            $this->Display_Resolution = !( IS_NULL( $_COOKIE['users_resolution'] )) ? substr(trim($_COOKIE['users_resolution']),0,16) : "N/A";
        }
        $this->Page_Action = substr(trim(&$xPageAction),0,32);
     }
     // Initialize Session objSession for $_SESSION
     public function CreateSession($xSessionId = null, &$xSessionObj = null ) {
        $this->Creation_Dt = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', time( ));
        $this->UpdateSessionClassData(&$xSessionId, &$xSessionObj);
       // $this->WriteSessionToDb();
        }

     // Update Session objSession for $_SESSION
     public function UpdateSession($xSessionId = null, &$xSessionObj = null, $xPageAction = "N/A" ) {
        $this->UpdateSessionClassData(&$xSessionId, &$xSessionObj, &$xPageAction);
       // $this->WriteSessionActivityToDb();
        }

      // Writes the session data to database
      public function WriteSessionToDb($xUserType = "Web") {
              $objConnect = new clsDb;
              $objDb = $objConnect->GetDbConnection($xUserType);
              //$objDb = $this->GetDbConnection($xUserType);
              $_InsertSQL = new PDOStatement;
              $_InsertSQL = $objDb->prepare("INSERT INTO T_SESSION_STATS(" .
                  "F_ACTION_DT, F_SESSION_ID, F_SESSION_IP_ADDRESS, F_BROWSER_TYPE," .
                  "F_DISPLAY_RESOLUTION, F_PAGE_REQUESTED, F_PAGE_REQUEST_PARAMS," .
                  "F_REQUEST_METHOD, F_IS_HTTPS_IND, F_IS_LOGGED_IN_IND, F_USER_KEY)" .
                  "Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(1, $this->Action_Dt );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(2, $this->Session_Id );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(3, $this->Session_IP_Address );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(4, $this->Browser_Type );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(5, $this->Display_Resolution );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(6, $this->Page_Requested );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(7, $this->Page_Request_Params );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(8, $this->Request_Method );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(9, $this->Is_Https_Ind );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(10, $this->Is_Logged_In_Ind );
              $_InsertSQL->bindParam(11, $this->User_Key );
          try {
            $objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $objDb->beginTransaction();
            $_InsertSQL->execute();
            $objDb->commit();
            unset($objDb);
          } catch (Exception $e) {
            $objDb->rollBack();
            echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            unset($objDb);
            unset($objConnect);
          }
      }

        // Writes the session data to database
        public function WriteSessionActivityToDb($xUserType = "Web",$xPageAction = "N/A") {
                $objConnect = new clsDb;
                $objDb = $objConnect->GetDbConnection($xUserType);
                //$objDb = $this->GetDbConnection($xUserType);
                $_InsertSQL = new PDOStatement;
                $_InsertSQL = $objDb->prepare("INSERT INTO T_SESSION_ACTIVITIES(" .
                    "F_ACTION_DT, F_SESSION_ID, F_SESSION_IP_ADDRESS, " .
                    "F_PAGE_REQUESTED, F_PAGE_REQUEST_PARAMS," .
                    "F_REQUEST_METHOD, F_PAGE_ACTION, F_IS_HTTPS_IND, F_IS_LOGGED_IN_IND, F_USER_KEY)" .
                    "Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(1, $this->Action_Dt );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(2, $this->Session_Id );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(3, $this->Session_IP_Address );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(4, $this->Page_Requested );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(5, $this->Page_Request_Params );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(6, $this->Request_Method );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(7, substr(trim($xPageAction),0,32));
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(8, $this->Is_Https_Ind );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(9, $this->Is_Logged_In_Ind );
                $_InsertSQL->bindParam(10, $this->User_Key );
            try {
              $objDb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
              $objDb->beginTransaction();
              $_InsertSQL->execute();
              $objDb->commit();
              unset($objDb);
              unset($objConnect);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
              $objDb->rollBack();
              unset($objDb);
              echo "Failed: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: hey removed a bogus line that on the else side... typo only so don't think that was the issue.

Comment: What issue do you see? Do changes not appear or is `$_SESSION['objSession']` null when you check?

Comment: thx Jim - isset tests true on secondary page requests but the values of the properties that were set via originally with the CreateSession method are null. I can create another simple $_SESSION variable along side the same code that is just text/numeric and it will persist every single time regardless.

Comment: please post your object definition too.

Comment: what happens if you put `session_write_close()` before the end of the file (without using un-/serialize)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in your `clsSession` class. This is using `&`. Since the session object is serialized these references aren't stored correctly. Try removing these (i.e. change `UpdateSessionClassData` and `UpdateSession` to remove the `&` from parameters) and see if this sorts the issue.

Comment: Jim - thx man... i got rid of passing by reference flawlessly on hundreds of iterations.   - Thank you so much.... BTW please let me know if you have any ideas on how i can not have to make tmpobj property changes and then having to re-assign that entire object back to the session['objSession'] each time i make changes.  I was hoping to have intellisense and being able to make direct changes to object properties.

Comment: @TimWiley If I remember correctly updating objects in the session should work without having to reinsert into the session.

Answer (score -1):

to start, put `session_start();` before `require_once` and add `var_dump($_SESSION)` for debug.

Comment: Putting `session_start()` before the require is not a good idea. PHP serializes objects which go into the session and the class definition must exist when unserializing.

Comment: exactly i originally had the session_start() first and same problem but i moved it to second line because it has to be there first for the session object.  regardless the session itself is persisting the objSession object the problem is the properties set within the object are not persisting.  Simple session variables work fine in the same code but problem only occurs when assigning an object.